# Amazon Redshift - COPY statement curlerror; is there a SQL based workaround for curl timeout?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, curl, amazon-redshift

I'm copying a large volume of data from S3 into redshift.
The data is stored in a series of hierarchical folders. At the bottom level of the folders [depth of n=3] there are files without an extension; the contents are formatted as JSON. Another note: it is not partitioned data either.

Previously this data was being crawled/read by Athena, but that was very slow and ran into a lot of timeouts. (2tb, hundreds of billions or trillions rows in source table)

I am now attempting to use a copy statement to copy a several hundred gigabyte subset of the data into redshift from s3. The table I created to copy it into:

```sql
CREATE TABLE data_raw (
json_raw SUPER
)
```

When running the copy statement, I get the following error after about 45 minutes:

```
ERROR: S3CurlException: Connection timed out after 50001 milliseconds, CurlError 28, multiCurlError 0, CanRetry 1, UserError 0 Detail: 
----------------------------------------------- 
error: S3CurlException: Connection timed out after 50001 milliseconds, CurlError 28, multiCurlError 0, CanRetry 1, UserError 0 code: 9002 [...] query: #### location: s3_utility.cpp:665 process: padbmaster [pid=200##]
```

I have read [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25454477/amazon-redshift-bulk-insert-vs-copying-from-s3) regarding copy statements in redshift, looked into [this question about curl timeouts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58218149/laravel-curl-error-28-when-upload-files-to-aws-s3-bucket) and read [this git issue](https://github.com/aws-amplify/aws-sdk-ios/issues/773) regarding some of the timeout properties. Granted, the linked issue seems to be for a different part of AWS tooling than what I am using.

What I want to know:

- is this something that can be resolved either via redshift or S3 configs? (I get the impression that it cannot be)
- what is a workaround that can be used?
- is part of the issue that the table I used just has a single `SUPER` column?

Other things to know:

- I already validated the json
- The size of the data subset I am trying to copy is above 200gb [not sure since the calculation failed at some point past that number]